# AWK to filter to files if their columns match

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I basically am working with two files (file1 and file2).  The goal is to write a script that pulls rows from file1, if columns 1,2,3 match between files1 and files2.  Here's the code I have been playing with:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2$3]++;next};c[$1$2$3] > 0' file1 file2 > filtered.txt
```

ile1 and file2 both look like this (but has many more columns):

```
name1 0 c 
name1 1 c
name1 2 x
name2 3 x
name2 4 c
name2 5 c
```

The awk code I provided isn't producing any output. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does `pulls rows from` mean `print` or `delete` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

your delimiter isn't pipe, try this

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {c[$1,$2,$3]++; next} c[$1,$2,$3]' file1 file2 > filtered.txt
```

or

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {c[$0]++; next} c[$0]' file1 file2 > filtered.txt
```

however, if you're matching the whole line perhaps easier with `grep`

```
$ grep -xFf file1 file2 > filtered.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{key=$1 FS $2 FS $3} NR==FNR{file2[key];next} key in file2' file2 file1
```